# Errors with generics

Tags: c#, generics

I'm having a problem with c#.
I'm trying to make some java code working

I have this method`

```
public static E JobFromJson <E, I, T, K>(String json, TaskType task) where E : Job<I, T, K>
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task.GetJob (task)> (json);
}
```

the "return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (json)" should return an object of a type E that extends Job
the Task.GetJob(task) should return a specific type which extends Job

the code doesn't compile and I receive these error:

in the method definition:
The type 'I' cannot be used at type parameter 'I' in the generic type or method 'SagaApi.Job'. There is no boxing or parameter conversion from 'I' to SagaApi.Item

in the declaration:
The type arguments for method 'SagaApi.Task.GetJob(SagaAPI.TaskType)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

also when I call the method from the class SagaApi.Job I do this:

```
public static E FromJson<E, A, B, C> (String json, TaskType taskType) where E : Job<A, B, C>
{
    return Task.JobFromJson (json, taskType);
}
```

I get the same errors

In java the code (which I didn't do) looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <E extends Job<?, ?>> E jobFromJson(String json)
{
    return (E)new Gson().fromJson(json, this.jobClass);
}
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: THis is how the Task class looks like. I haven't made the full GetJob(task) method yet but it will be something like this:

```
namespace SagaAPI
{
    public static class Task
    {

        /**
        * Obtain the {@link Job} from the json
        * @param json the json string
        * @return the {@link Job} object
        */
        public static E Job<E, I, T, K> JobFromJson<I, T, K> (string json, TaskType task) where E : Job<I, T, K>
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task.GetJob (task)> (json);
        }

        /**
        * Obtain the {@link AnswerContainer} from the json
        * @param json the json string
        * @return the {@link AnswerContainer} object
        */
        public static E AnswerFromJson <E, K> (String json, TaskType task) where E : AnswerContainer<K>
        {
            return (E) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task.GetAnswer (task)> (json);
        }

        private static Type GetJob<I, T, K> (TaskType task)
        {
            if (task == TaskType.RELATION)
                return typeof (ConceptJob<I, T, K>);

            else if (task == TaskType.COLOR)
                return typeof (AnnotationJob<I, T, K>);

            else
                return typeof (ValidationJob<I, T, K>);
        }

        private static Type GetAnswer<K> (TaskType task)
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is _Task.GetJob (task)_? can you provide sample code for this method?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] and format errors with `>`. Right now it is very unclear how `Task.Xxxx` look like making it very hard to provide you meaningful guidance.

Comment: so, in this case, possibly you help reflection

Comment: I added the full code of the Task class

Comment: It is not easy to substitute a `Type` value for a generic parameter, you need to use reflection to do that. There is no syntax that supports `Type<typeof(x)>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should pass generic arguments when call generic function, if compiler can't get it from parameter or return value, so here

```
Task.GetJob (task)
```

should be

```
Task.GetJob<I, T, K>(task)
```

next, you can't pass type variable as generic type parameter, but you can use reflection like this

```
public static E JobFromJson <E, I, T, K>(String json, TaskType task) where E : Job<I, T, K>
{
    var method= typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(m=>m.Name == "DeserializeObject" && m.GetGenericArguments().Length==1 && m.GetParameters().Length==1).Single();
    var concreteMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(Task.GetJob<I, T, K>(task));

    return (E)concreteMethod.Invoke(null, new object[]{json});
}
```

Comment: how slow is using reflection and linq btw? This will be in a videogame. Thanks a lot by the way, this works

Comment: @Epilogue, as you see _method_ is same on every call, so you can save it as static field, and get just once. as for concrete method, you also can cache it, to avoid using reflection on type which already used

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Task.GetJob(task)` `returns` `Job<I, T, K>` your signature should be:

```
public static Job<I, T, K> JobFromJson<I, T, K>(string json, TaskType task)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task.GetJob<I, T, K>(task)> (json);
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work (I receive the same error), Also the Task.GetJob(task) should return a type (for example typeof (TextAnnotationJob) which extends Job) which is the type used by the Json deserializer to create the object.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this

```
public static Job<I, T, K> JobFromJson<I, T, K> (string json, TaskType task) where I : Item where T : AnswerContainer<K>
```

Basically I should have specified each generic type again  as in the Job class

Thanks to everyone